# Problems accessing uccapi.dll COM interface C++

Tags: c++, com, c++builder-2010, uccapi

I'm working on a project involving the Microsoft Unified Communications Client API; uccapi.dll. I'm also using Codegear C++Builder 2010, not Visual Studio. After registering the dll with regsvr32 and importing it as type library into C++Builder 2010, uccapi_tlb- and uccapi_ocx-files were generated. When having imported these into my new project I'm trying to follow the [msdn guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd230150(v=office.12).aspx) for creating a Office Communicator Client able of signing into the Office Communication server.

In this regard I have two questions:

- What is the correct way of accessing the com-interfaces made available through the ocx?

I've so far found several ways of creating access points, such as.

```
TCOMIUccPlatform plat;
plat = CoUccPlatform::Create();
```

and

```
IUccPlatformPtr im;
im = CreateComObject(CLSID_UccPlatform);
```

and

```
IUccPlatform* pIUccPlatform;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UccPlatform, 
                      NULL, 
                      CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                      __uuidof(IUccPlatform), 
                     (void**)&pIUccPlatform);
```

and

```
IUccPlatformPtr pIPlat;
pIPlat.CreateInstance(__uuidof(IUccPlatform));
```

The three first seem to work well. The latter will give me an Assertion failed: intf!=0 error with 0×40000015 exception. Using any of the three top ones I can access methods and initialize the **platform** interface.

However when trying any of the same tactics to access any other interface, such as **IUccContext**, **IUccUriManager** or **IUccUri**, all of which have a clsid defined in the _tlb.h file, I either get a "class not registered" error in the first two cases, or a hresult failure in the third case. Which brings me to my next question.

- Using ole-viewer all interfaces are registered as they should. Why wouldn't all co-creatable classes in the dll be registered when registering the dll? And what could be the reasons why don't they act similarly?

*Edit1 from UCCAPILib_tlb.h:*

```
// 
// COCLASS DEFAULT INTERFACE CREATOR
// CoClass  : UccPlatform
// Interface: TCOMIUccPlatform
//
typedef TCoClassCreatorT<TCOMIUccPlatform, IUccPlatform, &CLSID_UccPlatform, &IID_IUccPlatform> CoUccPlatform;
// 
// COCLASS DEFAULT INTERFACE CREATOR
// CoClass  : UccUriManager
// Interface: TCOMIUccUriManager
// 
typedef TCoClassCreatorT<TCOMIUccUriManager, IUccUriManager, &CLSID_UccUriManager, &IID_IUccUriManager> CoUccUriManager;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already being discussed in detail in the [Embarcadero forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=40273).

Comment: discussed and solved.  And the OP's question is word for word identical so it was copy and pasted from the above link.